# .NET TcpClient Empty & Non empty return stream

Tags: c#, .net, tcpclient

The below works fine when there is data returned. It is valid however for an empty stream to be returned at which point the below hangs on stream.read().  How can I refactor it to cater for both cases?

```
        using(TcpClient client = new TcpClient(_server, _port))
        using(NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

            byte[] myReadBuffer = new byte[1024];

            int numberOfBytesRead = 0;

            var message = new List<Byte> ();

            do{
                numberOfBytesRead = stream.Read(myReadBuffer, numberOfBytesRead, myReadBuffer.Length);

                message.AddRange(myReadBuffer.Take(numberOfBytesRead));

            }
            while(stream.DataAvailable);         

            return message.ToArray();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the code example correctly, all you really want to do is read all of the bytes from the socket (i.e. the TCP connection) and then return them as a `byte[]`. If that's the case, then this would be much better:

```
    using(TcpClient client = new TcpClient(_server, _port))
    using(NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
    using(MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream())
    {
        stream.CopyTo(output);
        return output.ToArray();
    }
```

As a general rule, I *strongly* advise against using the `DataAvailable` property. In this case, it's especially inappropriate because all it does is check to see how many bytes can be read from the stream and if it's non-zero, returns `true`. An empty stream will never have bytes available, and for that matter you will never detect the end of the stream even when the stream isn't empty (i.e. there's no way to tell when the other end is done sending you data).

If I've misunderstood and you really just want to return the bytes that are immediately available, then I can't provide an answer without more context. The *correct* way to implement this would be to use asynchronous I/O, with a layer that understands the overall structure of the stream (i.e. where data boundaries are), but the details required to implement that aren't present in your question, so it's not possible to provide specific advice along those lines.

Comment: Your understanding is correct. Unfortunately the code now blocks at the .CopyTo for both cases. I'm thinking this might be something peculiar to NetworkStream.

Comment: @MylesMcDonnell: if `CopyTo()` blocks, then the remote endpoint is misbehaving. I.e. it should be doing a graceful closure on the connection when it's done sending. Note that assumes the flow is "connect, send all data, close connection". If you want to keep the connection open so more data can be sent later, you need to change your protocol so that there's a mechanism to delimit individual transmissions on the same connection (e.g. precede the transmission with a byte length)

Comment: Interesting point about async IO;  The response stream is simply a byte[] of arbitrary length, it's does not need to be interpreted/parsed in any way.

Comment: @MylesMcDonnell: it seems to me the immediate question is, do you expect the server to close the connection when it's done sending the response? If so, then if `CopyTo()` blocks, it seems the server isn't closing the connection. If you _don't_ expect the connection to be closed, then you need to explain how you expect to determine the length of any given response on that connection. Is it possible you should be using the `HttpClient` class instead? What kind of server are you dealing with here?

Comment: It's a TCP server I have written in Erlang so I suspect you are correct; the server implementation is erroneous.

Answer (score 1):

You can never tell whether more data will be coming or whether the stream is depleted. The remote side **must** signal you the end of the stream.

By closing or shutting down the socket you will read `0` bytes which is your signal to stop reading.

Or, make the remote side send data signaling the end of the stream.

Your use of `DataAvailable` is a bug (99% of such uses are bugs). `DataAvailable` is poison. It tells you how much data is ready to be read in a non-blocking way right now. 1us later the answer might be different.

You need to throw this away.

Comment: Yes, I have done, thank you.  This is my first foray into network programming at this level so I'm making every mistake in the book.